# Internet access status, windows 7 event viewer

Tags: internet, connection, logging, event-viewer, events

I have a pc working 24/7 and the internet connection disconnect and reconnect several times in the day, and I would like to know log history of the internet status logged by this pc, is it possible using even viewer and what is the recommended "custom view"

Thanks

Comment: I think you want this. Try to google first. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/use-network-troubleshooter-event-logs-to-solve-network-problems

Comment: I just want to see the history of internet status

Comment: Many modems/routers maintain this history as part of their logs.

Answer (score 0):

The Event Viewer shows system events, the internet is outside the system. You could use a free tool [Total Network Monitor](http://www.softinventive.com/products/total-network-monitor/) which states: "Total Network Monitor is a free software program for the continuous monitoring of the local network, individual computers, and services that require careful attention and thorough control. TNM will alert you of any problem in advance and generate a detailed report on the circumstances of the failure." and/or check the logs on your router...